# If $(x^y)^z = x^{y\cdot z}$, why does $(-5)^{2^{0.5}}$not equal $(-5)^1$?

Tags: exponentiation

[As shown by Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E2%29%5E0.5+%3D%3D+%7Cx%7C), $(x^2)^{0.5}$ is equal to |x|, but if you tried to simplify it to $x^{2\times {0.5}}$, it would just be $x^1$, or $x$.

Is there some unwritten rule about that distribution law that means you can't do it with fractional exponents?

Edit: What confuses me the most is how [Wolfram Alpha also believes $(x^2)^{0.5}$ = x](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+%28x%5E2%29%5E0.5) while actually showing a graph of |x|

Comment: Yes. For rational values of $q$, the value $x^q$ is only defined for positive values of $x$.

Comment: @5xum don't you mean *fractional* values of q? $(-5)^2$ is very well defined, where neither -5 is positive nor 2 is irrational.

Comment: Oh no, not again ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With iterated exponentiation the order of the operations are read from the top down. So in your example one has
$$(-5)^{2^{0.5}}=(-5)^{\left (2^{0.5} \right )}=(-5)^{\sqrt{2}}$$
which is undefined over the reals. Also note that in general 
$$x^{y^{z}} \neq x^{yz}$$

Comment: I was confused about the whole weird-dollar-signs-everywhere thing until I realised MathJax is blocked thanks to a https/http mismatch. This answer explains a lot, thanks.

Comment: Actually now that you've edited it I don't understand anything. The ((-5)^2)^0.5 going to (25)^0.5 made more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, $$(x^y)^z \ne x^{yz} \text{for negative $x$.}$$

This is because if $x \not \in \mathbb R^+$ then $x^y$ is not well defined for $y \not \in \mathbb Z$. In this particular case, $(-5^2)^{0.5}$ becomes, $25^{0.5}$. This is generally defined to be $\sqrt{25} = 5$. Your question is the same as asking why the sqaure root function has one value for one $x$, even though the function $f(x)=x^2$ is many one. This is because, contrary to what many people think, the square root *is not* an inverse of the square function, simply because the square function is not invertible, being many-one.

For a weak analogy, $\tan^{-1}(\tan(x))$ is not necessarily equal to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we have grouping symbols we work from the inside out , following PEMDAS , WIA included. If you want the exponents to cancel do it this way , $$ (x^{0.5})^2$$

Your numerical example becomes $$((-5)^{0.5})^2 = ( \sqrt{-5})^2 = (i \sqrt{5})^2 = i^2 5 = -5 $$

And in general for real numbers x , $$( \sqrt{x})^2 = x$$ $$\sqrt{x^2} = |x| $$

Put it in WIA to see what it gives you.